# ngModel with select list

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel

I am having trouble outputting a value from a select element.

```
<select 
([ngModel])="office_hour_start" 
name="office_hour_start">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let time of times"
    value="{{time.i}}">
    {{ time.i }}
  </option>
</select>
```

This setup has worked for me here:

```
<select 
  [(ngModel)]="employee_id" 
  name="employee_id" 
  class="form-control">
    <option 
      *ngFor="let employee of employees"
      value="{{employee.id}}">
      {{ employee.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the setup that worked for you, One additional suggestion would be:

```
// When using an ngModel, an event emitter () should be inside the input [] always 
// Though there is an instance where you can use it separately [ngModel] for Input (ngModelChange) for event emitter
<select [(ngModel)]="employee_id"           
        name="employee_id" 
        class="form-control">

    <option *ngFor="let employee of employees"
            value="{{employee.id}}">       // use [value]="employee.id" if you're assigning a dynamic value
        {{ employee.name }}
    </option>

</select>
```

> And for the case of the **office_hour_start** is its ngModel. You used
>   **([ngModel])**="office_hour_start" instead of **[(ngModel)]**="office_hour_start" putting the parenthesis inside the brackets [] is the way to fix it.

Had created a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-select-ngmodel) for your reference

Comment: The only thing I want is for the value to be selected. I am making an api call which uses this value as part of the URL. Nothing shows up in this.office_hour_start. It's ridiculous. I had the employee select as reference to what has worked before.

Comment: @Prozak had created a Stackblitz demo for your reference. Had updated my comment as well with the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-select-ngmodel - The case for the office_hour_start is its ngModel. You used ([ngModel])="office_hour_start"  instead of [(ngModel)]="office_hour_start" putting the parenthesis inside the brackets [] is the way to fix it.

Comment: thank you so much you have saved me from scratching my eyes out. The parenthesis was the problem.

Comment: @Prozak If the solution helped you, mind if you'll upvote and mark the answer as an accepted one? that would be of a great help. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select ng-options="time as time.i for time in office_hour_start track by time.id" ng-model="selected">
<option value="{{time.i}}">{{time.i}}</option>
</select>
```

hope this helps, use ng-options rather than ng-for

Comment: Doesn't seem to work : / Have never used that style before so going to take a while to troubleshoot it

Comment: Please also refer to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions for proper uses.